# How to set the android app theme in java,

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I want to allow the user change the theme from the **entire** app by clicking a button,
So I want to know if there is a way to **change the app theme** within java code.

Comment: Create a button, add a listener to it and, when it's clicked, change the UI accordingly

Comment: I  know how to make a button, but I don’t know how to change the theme within java code,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`setTheme()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) method on a Context.

Be sure to pay attention to the note in the documentation- you need to call `setTheme()` before you instantiate any Views.

If you change themes while your application is open, you will need to recreate your Activity for the changes to show.

Comment: Thanks, By the way did you know of an ease way to restart my activity?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ThemeSwitcher extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private boolean isThemeSwitch = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (isDefault() == false) {// Default theme defined in Style file.
            setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.theme_switcher);
        findViewById(R.id.switchTheme).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.switchTheme) {
            switchTheme();
            isThemeSwitch = true;
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if (isThemeSwitch) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThemeSwitcher.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    private SharedPreferences getPreference() {
        return getSharedPreferences("theme", 0);
    }

    private void switchTheme() {
        if (isDefault()) {
            getPreference().edit().putBoolean("theme", false).commit();
        }
        else {
            getPreference().edit().putBoolean("theme", true).commit();
        }
    }

    private boolean isDefault() {
        boolean isDef = true;
        isDef = getPreference().getBoolean("theme", false);
        return isDef;
    }
}
```